# How do I pass in arguments to a curled script, that has been piped into the Python process?

Tags: python, shell, curl

I have a Python script on a Github gist, which I can curl from my terminal with

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../script.py
```

The script has a main function that is executed, and I can pipe the output of the curl statement to Python, which executes the script.

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../script.py | python
```

The above statement works, but I want to provide some command line arguments to the script, without having to download it to a file. The problems I am facing are that the Python command treats any text following it as what to execute, and not as arguments for the piped file, so

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../script.py | python arg1 arg2
```

Does not work, nor does

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../script.py arg1 arg2 | python
```

How can I pass in both arguments to the file, either as standard input or command line options that my script can read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From CLI help:

> `-`      : program read from stdin (default; interactive mode if a tty)

So what you want is:

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../script.py | python - arg1 arg2
```

Note however, that `-` will also appear in `sys.argv` (in place of the script's filename)

```
$ echo "import sys; print sys.argv" | python - arg1 arg2
['-', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

Answer (score 0):

you could save the script locally and then execute it.

```
curl -o some_filename.py some_link
python some_filename.py arg1 arg2
```

you can also save a curl output to file with:

```
curl some_link > some_file.py
```